# How to catch AJAX beforeSend event in GWT RPC

Tags: java, ajax, gwt, asynchronous, gwtp

Consider the following example with ajax pattern

```
$.ajax({
        url: "someUrl",          
        beforeSend: function(){
           executeBeforeSend();
        },
        error: function(){
         //some error
        },
         success: function(){
         //some success function
        }
    });
```

If we there is `beforeSend` whick executes just before the server call.

Now we all know that GWT RPC use Ajax to server `asynchronous` calls.

```
private class MessageCallBack implements AsyncCallback<Message> {
      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
         /* server side error occured */

      }
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Message result) {
          /* server returned result, show user the message */
      }    
   }
```

But ,there is no method like `onBeforeSend`  etc.. How to `catch` that `event`?

Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [`RpcRequestBuilder`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/rpc/RpcRequestBuilder.html) that returns a subclass of `RequestBuilder` where you've overridden the `send()` methods.

Comment: Thanks thomos for prompt reply.Is there any way to cop up  this with `gwtp` pattern where I am using action handlers ?? I just need this event before the `execute` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [javaQuery](https://github.com/phil-brown/javaQuery) library to handle this. *javaQuery* is a partial port of jQuery to Java, and as such has all of the expected *Ajax* methods:

```
$.ajax(new AjaxOptions().url("someUrl").dataType("json").type("GET")//get and json are default anyway
                        .beforeSend(new Function() {
                            @Override
                            public void invoke($ javaQuery, Object... params) {
                                executeBeforeSend();
                            }
                        })
                        .error(new Function() {
                            @Override
                            public void invoke($ javaQuery, Object... params) {
                                AjaxError error = (AjaxError) params[0];
                                Log.err("Error %d: %s", error.status, error.reason);
                            }
                        })
                        .success(new Function() {
                            @Override
                            public void invoke($ javaQuery, Object... params) {
                                if (params[0] instanceof JSONObject) {
                                    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) params[0];
                                    //TODO
                                }
                                else {
                                    JSONArray array = (JSONArray) params[0];
                                    //TODO
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        .complete(new Function() {
                            @Override
                            public void invoke($ javaQuery, Object... params) {
                                executeComplete();
                            }
                        }));
```

Comment: Actually ,with this I have to change all my RPC structure ..though thanks for trying to help :)